# I have list of Snapshots, But i want to get SnapshotName and Size ,SnapshotID using boto3 python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have list of snapshots details. Example: `[{snap-1234, snap-3456, snap-7685, snap-1111, snap-2222}]`
How to iterate one by one and to get the snapshot name, size and snapshot id using python, boto3 docs?

Comment: have you tried describe_snapshots() or Snapshot('id') methods in boto3?

Comment: What did you try so far ? Please provide some code you tried already. Also, you may read the online documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with snapshot id list.

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
snapshot_ids = ['snap-xxxxxxxx']

snapshots = ec2.snapshots.filter(Filters=[{'Name':'snapshot-id','Values':snapshot_ids}])

def get_name(tags):
    
    if   tags == None: return None
    elif len(filter(lambda tag: tag.get('Key') == 'Name', tags)) == 0: return None
    else: return list(map(lambda tag: tag['Value'], filter(lambda tag: tag.get('Key') == 'Name', tags)))[0]

for snapshot in snapshots:
    print(get_name(snapshot.tags), snapshot.volume_size, snapshot.snapshot_id)
```